# ¿Cómo utilizar funciones con tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, tkinter

He estado programando una agenda telefónica en Python, utilizando la librería tkinter. Les dejaré un ejemplo simple de las entradas necesarias y la función que haría que estas entradas se guarden.

Tengan en cuenta que la ventana creada recibirá el nombre de Ventana; las entradas necesarias para añadir un nuevo contacto serían las siguientes.

```
Nombre=StringVar.()
NombreEnt=Entry(Ventana, textvariale=Nombre, width=30)

Apellido=StringVar.()
ApellidoEnt=Entry(Ventana, textvariale=Apellido, width=30)

Celular=StringVar.()
Celularnt=Entry(Ventana, textvariale=Celular, width=30)
```

Lo que plantee para esta situación fue crear un diccionario en el que se relacionen los nombres y los números celulares, esta se llama Guardar y está asociada a un botón que lleva el mismo nombre.

```
Contactos={}

def Guardar():
    nombre=Nombre.get()
    celular=Celular.get()
    Contactos[nombre]=celular

GuardarBtn=Button(text='Guardar',command=Guardar())
```

El problema es que le diccionario sigue en blanco luego de utilizar el botón. He estado utilizando esta biblioteca recientemente, así que aún no tengo claro algunos conceptos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parámetro `command` se le pasa el `nombre` o referencia de la función a usar, tu le pasas la salidad de la función (`None` en este caso).

Si haces esto:

```
GuardarBtn=Button(text='Guardar',command=Guardar())
```

Cuando se instancia el objeto `GuardarBtn` **se ejecuta la función** `Guardar` y `command` almacena el retorno de esta función, en vez de la referencia a ella para poder llamarla cuando el botón sea pulsado.

**No se usan paréntesis** (lo cual equivale a llamar a la función) cuando se le pasa el parámetro `command`, solo se le pasa el nombre:

```
GuardarBtn=Button(text='Guardar',command=Guardar)
```

Si necesitas llamar a una función que tiene parámetros de entrada tienes que usar funciones `lambda` (también conocidas como funciones anónimas). Imaginemos que queremos que un botón imprima el diccionario al ser pulsado. Para ello, necesitamos usar la función `print` y pasarle como argumento el diccionario, si hacemos `command = print(Contactos)` veremos como, nada más ejecutar el código, se imprime nuestro diccionario vacío, pero al pulsar el botón no pasa nada por lo explicado antes. En este caso es cuando son de utilidad las funciones `lambda`:

```
ImprimirBtn = Button(text='Guardar', command = lambda: print(Contactos))
```

Te dejo un ejemplo totalmente funcional basado en tu código, para que veas el funcionamiento de lo anterior:

```
import tkinter as tk

ventana = tk.Tk()

nombre = tk.StringVar()
tk.Entry(ventana, textvariable=nombre, width=30).grid(row=0, column=1)
tk.Label(ventana, text = 'Nombre').grid(row=0, column=0)

apellido = tk.StringVar()
tk.Entry(ventana, textvariable=apellido, width=30).grid(row=1, column=1)
tk.Label(ventana, text = 'Apellido').grid(row=1, column=0)

celular = tk.StringVar()
tk.Entry(ventana, textvariable=celular, width=30).grid(row=2, column=1)
tk.Label(ventana, text = 'Celular').grid(row=2, column=0)

contactos={}

def guardar():
    nom = nombre.get()
    cel = celular.get()
    contactos[nom] = cel

guardar_btn = tk.Button(ventana, text='Guardar', command = guardar)
guardar_btn.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky = 'ew')

imprimir_btn = tk.Button(ventana, text='Guardar', command = lambda: print(contactos))
imprimir_btn.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky = 'ew')

ventana.mainloop()
```