# TypeError: missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, tkinter

me gustaria poder resolver dos dudas que me estan atormentando,soy nuevo en esto asique agradeceria cualquier consejo y acepto criticas constructivas.
en la anterior pregunta esta el porque de mi codigo y basicamente mis problemas son 2:

a la hora de generar una frase aleatoria solo coge una palabra de la lista (e.j:en vez de elegir **El perro** escoge o **El** o **perro**)

y el otro problema se encuentra a la hora de ejecutar las funciones para añadir frases nuevas. A la hora de ejecutarlo mediante un boton para que recoja lo escrito en Entry y lo guarde en un txt que puede ser o sujeto o accion me salta el siguiente error.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: guardar_suj() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sujeto'
```

adjunto el codigo para que puedan revisarlo y comentarme cualquier cosa.
buen dia y muchisimas gracias.

```
import random
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox

#parametros tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Excusaleria,creacion original de Ericcs")

#funciones
def aleat():
    Rsujeto = random.choice(sujetos)
    Raccion = random.choice(acciones)
    tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title="excusa", message="esque..." + Rsujeto + Raccion)


def guardar_suj(sujeto:str):
    with open ('sujetos.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(gentry + '\n')


def guardar_acc(accion:str):
    with open('acciones.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(gentry + '\n')

#opciones a elegir
sujetos = open('sujetos.txt', 'r').read().split()
sujetos = [sujeto.strip() for sujeto in sujetos]

acciones = open('acciones.txt', 'r').read().split()
acciones = [accion.strip() for accion in acciones]

#generar
boton = tkinter.Button(window, text="pulsame", command=aleat, width=40, height=20)
boton.pack()

#agregar contenido
entrada = tkinter.Entry(window)
entrada.pack()

gentry = entrada.get()

añadir = tkinter.Button(window, text="añadir sujeto", command=guardar_suj)
añadir.pack()

añadir_2 = tkinter.Button(window, text="añadir accion", command=guardar_acc)
añadir_2.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: El evento del botón lo que hace es llamar a la función, sin embargo no se le pasa ningún parámetro, por eso el error te dice que hace falta un argumento

Comment: @christian Entonces tendría q añadir un parámetro con () al command de los botones no?,en caso de que si, me podrias decir que tipo de parámetro me haría falta, muchisimas gracias y perdón por las preguntas tontas pero lo estoy estudiando de manera autodidacta y hay cosas q todavia me pillan bastante.

Comment: En realidad no iría un paréntesis, para eso se usan las lambda expressions,y para pones como parametro `sujeto` si al final usas otra variable que además no esta definida?

Comment: Para saber de las expresiones lambda puede ver esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83102/c%C3%B3mo-utilizar-funciones-con-tkinter)

Comment: muchísimas gracias,ya pude resolver esa parte,ahora solo me falta saber como aplicar la sentencia conjunta y estará casi terminado. @christian

Comment: Como así?, lo siento no te entendí

Comment: tengo una lista en un documento .txt al cual accedo con un open,el programa básicamente lo que hace es coge un sujeto (ej. ***un alíen*** ) y una acción (ej. ***me abdujo*** ) y los junta pseudoaleatoriamente en frase (_un alíen me abdujo_),el problema es que en vez de darme la oración entera ( ***un alíen*** ) lo que hace es darme una de las 2 palabras ( ***un***  o  ***alíen*** ) @christian

Comment: Como tienes la variable `sujeto`? Y `acciones`?

Comment: `sujetos = open('sujetos.txt', 'r').read().split()
sujetos = [sujeto.strip() for sujeto in sujetos]

acciones = open('acciones.txt', 'r').read().split()
acciones = [accion.strip() for accion in acciones]`    @christian

Comment: Mmmm podrías hacer un print y añadir el resultado a tu pregunta